# Python function name ... is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Im doing some python web content requests and I want to make some functions in my code, but there is one error and I dont know why it´s showing.
My code looks like this:

```
def tempRequest(tree, heading):

    page = requests.get("http://10.0.0.3/admin/speedtest.php")
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    heading = tree.xpath('//a[@id="temperature"]/text()')
    return heading, tree

    tempRequest(tree, heading)
    heading = tree.xpath('//a[@id="temperature"]/text()')

    sheet = client.open("Database").sheet1

    sheet.insert_row(heading, 10)
    time.sleep(5)
```

> tempRequest(tree, heading) NameError: name 'tree' is not defined

Could you guys please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Because, on calling the (poorly indented) function, there is no `tree` in the global scope to pass to the function. How can you pass `tree` in `tempRequest(tree, heading)` when it doesn't exist prior to calling the function? Even without knowledge of python scoping, this is illogical.

Comment: So I should make it like this:
   `page = requests.get("http://10.0.0.3/admin/speedtest.php")`
   `tree = html.fromstring(page.content)`
    `heading = tree.xpath('//a[@id="temperature"]/text()')`

    `tempRequest(tree, heading)`

Comment: You pass values to the call, which are bound to the parameter names *inside* the function. As written, `tempRequest` doesn't need any arguments, though.

Comment: @PetrJelínek I think you're moving towards the right answer but please [edit] this into the original question so we can see where you're up to

Comment: @roganjosh I did.. But still, I have to define page, tree and heading in function and in global scope also..

Comment: You actually don't. Nice edit, but the answer by ruohola shows how none of these names need to be defined prior to calling the function. You don't have to initialise any variables and get in a chicken-or-egg situation, let the function _return_ the values to define them in the global scope.

Comment: @roganjosh I dont know why, but my code still doesnt work, even with edited code by ruohola. Let me show you the screenshot of my code, it will be better: https://snag.gy/fzgyPN.jpg

Comment: You're unpacking the values the wrong way around. The function returns _tree, heading_ but you're unpacking into _heading, tree_. The function is returning a tuple and you're switching the names around

Comment: @PetrJelínek please don't posts images of code (especially without line numbers!). But in your code you are calling the `tempRequest()` function three times. Once by taking the return values in wrong order, once without using the return values, and once without using the return values and passing parameters which it doesn't take.

Comment: These are very basic mistakes and I would advice you to go through some tutorials.

Comment: @ruohola I stand by my comment on your answer. The OP's implementation is incorrect here (see also my previous comment) but we can at least fix this one misunderstanding.

Comment: @roganjosh Okay, so I think that I figure out the way. So let me do a recap please and tell me if im wrong. First, I have to define a function without any position arguments, in this function i define tpage, tree and heading but return only tree and heading down, where i set them to the function. An If I need to use this function in my code again, i dont have to pass any arguments at all, thats how it worsk, but im not exactly sure why and how I get there.

Comment: Yes, if you define a function which takes no parameters, aka `def function_name():` you can never give any parameters to it. So you always have to call it as `function_name()` and never as `function_name(variable1, variable2)`.

Comment: @PetrJelínek that looks mostly correct but I suspect there's holes all over the place in your understanding here. You need to do some research about "python scope", "python function scope" etc, whatever pulls up the resources you need to get your head around this. It's a bit too much for us to cover here

Comment: I rolled back your edits. Your edited code couldn't have given you the old error. Make sure your question has a [mcve] and don't invalidate existing answers with edits.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, i agree with you, Im new in python and Im not very experienced programmer, so I will do some research, anyway, thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @PetrJelínek it's important research and I'm not sure what to point you to these days because some of my old links that I learned from are dead. But the key word is definitely "scope" and I wish you the best of luck. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some basic mistakes in your code, it should be like this:

```
def tempRequest():
    page = requests.get("http://10.0.0.3/admin/speedtest.php")
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    heading = tree.xpath('//a[@id="temperature"]/text()')
    return heading, tree

heading, tree = tempRequest()
sheet = client.open("Database").sheet1

sheet.insert_row(heading, 10)
time.sleep(5)
```

In your original code you're trying to pass variables to the function before you have defined them in your code. And you're not using your functions return values at all.